# проблема build Vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.
В `vue cli` прописывал подобные пути:

```
  @font-face 
    src: url("./assets/fonts/FuturaMediumC.woff")
```

или

```
src: url("@/assets/fonts/FuturaMediumC.woff")
```

Однако `build` в `vue cli` не скомпилировал правильные пути для `dist`, и оставляет в путях папку `assets`, коих нет в `dist`.
Как исправить эту проблему?